# What is the more up to date way of waiting for a transaction?

Tags: anchor, testing, anchor-client, program-test

When the following code is used during testing, I get the following warning:

```
[tsserver 6387] [I] The signature '(strategy: string, commitment?: Commitment): Promise<RpcResponseAndContext<SignatureResult>>' of 'provider.connection.confirmTransaction' is deprecated.
```

when calling:

```
await provider.connection.confirmTransaction(airdropTxHash, "confirmed");
```

What is the non-deprecated way of doing this? For more context I am using this for airdropping when doing testing:

```
const addFunds = async (
  provider: anchor.Provider,
  user: anchor.web3.PublicKey,
  amount: number
): Promise<void> => {
  const airdropTxHash = await provider.connection.requestAirdrop(user, amount);
  await provider.connection.confirmTransaction(airdropTxHash, "confirmed");
  console.log(`airdropped ${amount} to ${user.toBase58()}`);
};
```

Comment: can you add the deprecation warning text to your post to help others that run into similar issues find an answer?

Comment: done, though i don't think it adds a ton to the post :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, You can check out the documentation for the `@solana/web3.js` library in [here](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#confirmTransaction)

Looking at the definition of the `confirmTransaction` function, you need to provide a recent blockhash, so it would look something like this:

```
const bh = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

await connection.confirmTransaction({
    signature: txsig,
    blockhash: bh.blockhash,
    lastValidBlockHeight: bh.lastValidBlockHeight,
}, 'confirmed');
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Is this sensitive to any race conditions?